# HTML tag requirements for external php file?

Tags: php, forms

When I refer to a php document from within a form like this:

`<form action="action_page.php" method="post">`

Do I have to declare a doctype/head/body/etc in action_page.php?

Or do I just use the `<?php` and  `?>` tags?

Comment: That depends on what you're doing in action_page.php.

Comment: Are you outputting any HTML or are you executing some statements such as running a calculation or inputing data into a database and then redirecting to a confirmation page?...

Comment: I am never going to direct the user to visit action_page.php, instead I'm going to use action_page.php to process information to add to a database and then display the information on the original page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the program in the file `action_page.php` is executed, it should output a complete HTML document (or a content-type header that says it is something other than HTML, and a document in that format, or headers that tell the browser to request a different URL).

That includes the Doctype et al.

Comment: If it just processes the form and redirects to another page, the HTML tags are not required.

Comment: Unless action_page.php is doing some server side processing and redirecting the user.